# How can I create a JavaScript derived class from HTML5 Worker?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, inheritance, worker

I tried to create a new kind of Worker class in JS:

```
function ConnectedWorker(workerSrcURL, onConnect) {
  function filterOnConnect(rawPort, url) {
    if (url.indexOf(workerSrcURL) !== -1)
      onConnect(rawPort, url);
  }
  ChannelPlate.PortServer(workerSrcURL, filterOnConnect);

  Worker.call(this, workerSrcURL);
  this.onmessage = onConnect;
}
ConnectedWorker.prototype = {
  __proto__: Worker.prototype
};
```

but it fails on the Worker.call()

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Worker': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

Any hints?